# Why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18459/167850

I see no reason at all. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 13):

I didn't delete it, but I agree with the mod who did 100%. That was noise. It was a joke, frankly not a very funny one, which was posted as an answer. The entire content of your post was this:

> I think it would be a good idea to suspend all too high-rated people like Oli, Rinzwind, etc. for a year or two to let other people do something useful ;-)

That is clearly not answering the question, and not providing anything useful to the discussion. What's worse, it was posted on a pretty serious subject where the suspension of a high rep user was being discussed. That isn't something we (mods or users) take lightly so that makes your post even more delete-worthy.

But the main reason it was deleted was for the same reason *anything* on the site is deleted: it wasn't answering the question. If you felt it was so important, you should have left a comment.

Comment: Everyone is so serious here ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 it's well known that [we hate fun](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/203101). More seriously, come on! You've been an active user for years, surely by now you know that an answer should be providing an _answer_ and not a joke. And, in any case, the suspension of one of our highest rep users is not something to joke about.

Comment: This is meta... and some fun is useful at times. :-)

Comment: @Pilot6 sure. But why post an answer? And on such a serious subject? What really baffles me is that you would not understand why it was deleted!

Comment: I seriously don't. Why not leave it alone. But if it is so important that jokes are not allowed, well...OK.

Comment: @Pilot6 posting an answer that doesn't address the subject at hand and is nothing but a joke is not allowed anywhere. This would have been deleted no matter where it had been posted.

Comment: Anywhere? Do I deserve suspension for that? ;-) Inquisitors!!

Comment: Seriously. I posted that answer to reduce tension. I know it is a bad story, but without some sense of humor it is worse.

Comment: But it was **not** an answer. I could *understand* a comment, but it's clearly not an answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 humor is allowed [if it's not offensive, not snarky/sarcastic, and especially if it answers the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16496/241919)... and is it really to reduce tension? You didn't consider how high-rep users (like yourself) will react when reading that answer? And the fact that suspension is something that cannot be taken so lightly...

Comment: Windy does brag how most of his points come from quoting `manpage` on many occasions. I think this is the subtle suggestion Pilot is making which, is valid in comment form but obviously not as an answer. You do have the power to convert answer to a comment though...

Comment: Of course I have not association with Pilot or Putin and can only speculate. *Looks over shoulder for Russiagate*

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix why in the world would I take the time to convert a bad joke to a comment? We only do that when users who don't have enough rep to comment post something useful, but not quite an answer.  This was not useful at all and Pilot has more than enough rep to post a comment.

Comment: @terdon I'm not suggesting you **should** nor do I think you **would** just floating the generic idea that a *mod* **could** convert an answer to a comment. Personally I don't like the answer and if I saw it in comment form I would probably comment below that it wasn't nice or at the very least seek clarification. It sounds like it's being spun as a joke now. As guilty as I am of frequent corny or cheesy jokes I fail to see the humour in this one. Perhaps there is subconscious jealousy buried within? Perhaps if you fine me 50 points for cheesy jokes (and others for mean ones) we'll all stop :P

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is not really something universally dubbed a "post" here in AU. There are comments and answers.

Comments can be deleted or moved to discussion when the thread becomes too long, too much like an extended Q&A or too jovial.

Answers can be converted to a comment when a user doesn't have necessary rep to post a comment. Answers can be deleted when they are too personal or off-topic. I think your answer is rather a bit of both. This is how I would judged your case.

As far as assertion of being the answer being funny goes, I put you right up there with Muru as not being funny. Which is not a bad thing. I think yours and his answers are usually intelligent, succint and highly educational.

On this so-called answer of yours, whether it be construed a comment or not, I think suggesting banning Oli and/or Windy is over the top.

If you like a good joke though, I suggest trying our watered down Alberta Beer instead of Russian Vodka :)